# Navigation bar in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to Django and started learning . I want to add a navigation bar to different pages like [Menu],[Home],[Contact].

how can i do this using Django template ?
part of my template.

```
    <nav>
        <a href="{% url 'polls/detail' %}">Detail</a>
        <a href ="{% url 'polls/index'%}">Home</a>
        <a href ="{%url 'polls/contact'%}">Contact</a>
    </nav>

</header>
<section>
    {% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul id="choice">
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
            <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_test }}</a></li>
        {%  endfor %}

    </ul>
```

> Below ismy url.conf`

```
    patterns = [
    url(r'^index/$',views.index,name='index'),

    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail,name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/result/$',views.result,name='result'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$',views.vote,name='vote'),
    url(r'^contact/$',views.contact,name='contact'),
```

]`
Below is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse ,Http404,HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Question ,Choice
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    try:
        latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()
    except:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context=  {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list})



def detail(request,question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
        return render(request,'polls/detail.html', context=  {'question':question})
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exists")




def vote(request, question_id):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except(KeyError,Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request,'polls/detail.html',{
        'question':question,
        'error_message':'You did not select a choice'
    })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes+=1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('result',args=(question_id)))



def result(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/result.html', {'question': question})

def contact(request):
    return render(request,'polls/contact.html')
```

> Below is the error , I am getting
>       Reverse for 'polls/detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: It gives me error like no reverse url

Comment: Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/polls/index
'polls\index' could not be found

Comment: You're using the static and url tags wrong..  Honestly you'd be better off doing the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a name to the URLs in your urls.py then calling them in your template by their name.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/polls/about/', views.about.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^/polls/contact/', views.contact.as_view(), name='contact'),
    ...
]
```

template:
    `{% url 'about' %}`

See the documentation for more information:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url

https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Updated Answer:
Your detail, vote and result pages all point to a specific instance of your question model. This is shown by the `(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)` line in your urls.py and as part of your view function variables.

You will need to pass a valid question_id in your view context dictionary to your template, then include that question_id in your {% url %} tag.

So for example, if you wanted to add a link to the first question detail on your index page you would need to make the following changes:

In views.py:

```
def index(request):
    try:
        latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()
        question = latest_question_list[0]
    except:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context ={'latest_question_list': latest_question_list, 'question':question})
```

Then in your template you can link to the details of this specific question like so:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' question_id=question.id %}">Detail</a>
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /polls/index/
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/polls/index/
Django Version: 1.9.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$']